# Performance/Memory in Java for data generation over multiple files

Tags: java, performance, memory

Here is the problem:
1. Need to generate 1.000.000 entries/file(csv_extension) for 3 files.
1. The data between the 3 files is connected like this:
File 1 - Session
File 2 - Workflow
File 3 - Steps

File 2 needs to contain the generated Session_ID field from file 1 and File 3 needs the generated Workflow_ID field from file 2 so that their is a link between them. 
Session contain workflow and workflow contains steps.

How do I do this at generation time without performance and memory impact?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally doing just about anything carries a performance/memory impact, but anyway...

The most glaring awkward part of this problem is the CSV file. It's a plain text format, and that effectively renders each field you output into a variable-sized chunk. It's very difficult to get the greatest performance in file I/O (or any kind of memory I/O) when you can't exploit fixed-size assumptions about the memory chunks being written or read in bulk.

Contrast this to, say, outputting a million contiguous floating-point values to a binary file, where each one will write a 32-bit chunk. That can occur very quickly (milliseconds, e.g.)

Besides that, outputting as plain text involves a lexical conversion somewhere down the line, and that puts greater CPU strain even without considering what goes on in memory.

Without getting into the nitty-gritty details, which we shouldn't anyway before profiling (most micro-optimizations are best saved to be applied in hindsight after measuring), probably the most effective thing to exploit here initially is concurrency.

While you have these inter-file dependencies, a million entries should be relatively quite cheap to store temporarily in memory (provided each entry isn't likewise aggregating a hundred elements or anything like that). You should be able to compute and store this inter-dependent data in volatile memory without involving direct inter-file dependencies.

Computing the interdependent data is effectively a serial problem due to the order dependencies, so it has to be carried out in a single thread (unless you can do this simultaneously across session/workflow/steps on a per-entry level, at which point you can just parallelize the computation of entries).

Once computed in volatile memory, you can then parallelize the output of each of these three files.

Beyond that at this initial stage is probably just making sure you use an efficient API for the I/O and a reasonably compact data representation with good locality of reference for what you store in volatile memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `streams` (both input and output) to process files (large data) without consuming too much memory.

[Here's](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm) a nice article.

Simplified example:

```
FileReader in = null; 
FileWriter out = null; 
try { 
    in = new FileReader("input.txt"); 
    out = new FileWriter("output.txt"); 
    int c; 
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) { 
            out.write(c); 
        } 
}
finally { 
    if (in != null) { 
        in.close(); 
    } 
    if (out != null) { 
        out.close(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser but the problem is not writing to csv, I use  apache commons csv. To eliminate memory problem, I generate the first line then write it to csv and so on. The problem is when I generate the first file, session, I need the generated field session_id from this file(session) to be the same in second file, workflow.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance you are doing heavily I/O into 3 different files.

If you are using just a plain [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) or [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), this may slow down your processing.
The main reason is that you are writing just small chunks of data (a line of a CSV) but rather often to disk.

Therefore I would recommend to use a buffer to speed up the slower I/O by writing larger chunks but less often with either [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) or [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) wrapping your [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) or [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

A reasonable buffer size might be 64 KB.
Assuming a cluster size of 4 KB on your hard disk this will cache 16 blocks of data and then write them at once to your disk.

In terms of memory impact you should just ensure, that you only process one record during each processing step and write it followed by the linked records to disk without keeping it for later on.